# Retarded potentials are wrong? (if we are to consider the domain restriction onto $ t_{r}$)

Tags: electromagnetism, potential, maxwell-equations

I believe what I am considering is brand new, as I cannot find any specific use of this anywhere online and would like to know your thoughts

The solution to maxwells equations are:

$A(r,t)= \frac{\mu_0}{4\pi}\iiint \frac{J(r',t_{r})}{|r-r'|} d^3 r'$

$V(r,t)= \frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\iiint \frac{\rho(r',t_{r})}{|r-r'|} d^3 r'$

Where $t_{r}= t - \frac{|r-r'|}{c}$

Each contribution to the integral has to meet the condition that

$t_{r} > 0$

Otherwise we are evaluating the J and $\rho$ in the past, and the contribution these make to the integral should be zero

The condition imposed on t is therefore

$ t > \frac{|r-r'|}{c}$

For problems where r' is zero, such as a infinitely small hertzian dipole, or for problems with high symmetry, we can easily find a global domain restriction on t that applies to all  contributions of our integral. therefore we only need to find a global domain condition imposed  onto A to meet the requirement that $ t_{r} > 0$

But for problems where each element is a different distance away from "r" there must be a different domain restriction onto t for each contribution to our integral

Online I have found no such function that completely encorporates a domain restriction onto each element. without having to analyse each problem individually, and if there is a better way of doing it then the way I am about to suggest then I would appreciate links.

Consider the function,

$\int_{a}^{b} \delta(t-s)ds $

Given I choose some value of "t", this delta function will "compare" s with my chosen t value such that if t doesn't match s, then the integral is zero, However if t does match s, then the integral evaluates to 1. This integral will "itterate" s checking all values of s within the range A to B to see if it matches T.

This integral thus evaluates to zero if t isn't within the interval A to B and is 1 if t is within the Interval A to B

Translating it to the problem at hand. The restriction to t would be that $\frac{|r-r'|}{c}$ < t

Thus the domain restriction on T would be given by the function

$$\int_{\frac{|r-r'|}{c}}^{\infty} \delta(t-s)ds = L$$

This domain restriction applies to each contribution to A and $\rho$

Thus A and rho should be -

$A(r,t)= \frac{\mu_0}{4\pi}\iiint \frac{J(r',t_{r})}{|r-r'|} L d^3 r'$

$V(r,t)= \frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\iiint \frac{\rho(r',t_{r})}{|r-r'|} L d^3 r'$

If we are to obey the restrictions into $t_{r}$. This way would work as a general solution to any problem without having to analyse them individually

So my question is:
Is this correct? and if not, why. And also, are there any other methods of obeying the restriction onto $t_{r}$

Comment: What is the value of $t_r$ if $t<0$?

Comment: T cannot be less than zero as that means your evaluating the field as a time in the past , but if you want to know . look at the definition of $t_{r}$ t would be some negative number minus (|r-r'|)/c

Comment: Why would evaluating the field at a time in the past be a problem?

Comment: Obviously my equation assumes that the global time "T =0 " is the time at which any current distribution turns "on".

Comment: I guess T<0 would be allowed if you are defining your current and charge distrulibutions to follow the same function in negative time. however for a current distribution that gets turned on. the retarded time cannot be less than zero as the J function should be zero as it hasn't been turned on yet

Comment: Fortunately, there is already a way to implement 'turning $J$ on at time $t_0$". Either $J$ would be piece-wise defined, or you may write $J(t)H(t-t_0)$ where $H$ is [Heaviside's step function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function)

Comment: ahh thought I was the first aha, knew it would be too good to be true. both mine and H has the same properties. I still wonder why this isn't included in the definition of the potentials. else this is saying that the current distributions have existed in that state in all time and space which isn't useful. if you write it as an answer then I'll accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not necessary to add this switching on/off 'by hand'. All such information is already carried by the function $J(t)$. If you have a current $C(t)$ that you want to restrict to turn on at say $t_0$, you can define $J$ piece-wise

$$
J(t)=\cases{0 & $t<t_0$\\C(t) & $t>t_0$}
$$

A compact way of writing this is using [Heaviside's step function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function), $H$, where the above would read

$$
J(t)=H(t-t_0)C(t)
$$